# Getting the data from a NSTableView to a NSViewController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nstableview

I'd like to have a 'Detail view' for when the user double clicks on a row, I'm just not sure how to get the data to the NSViewController, so it can display the content. I'm using CoreData and I can't think of a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of steps you need to do here:

1. Make sure the table view is driven by a `NSArrayController` and that your controller for the table view (either a window controller or a view controller, or whatever) has that `NSArrayController` bound to an ivar so that you access it.
2. In your table controller set the double click action to a method in your controller and set the target to your controller.
3. In the double click method you can access the row by requesting the `-selectedObjects` from the `NSArrayController` and that resulting `NSArray` should have only one element in it.

From there you can then create your detail view or whatever else you want to do with it.  You can create a sheet and display it, open a modal window, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Cocoa bindings.
Apple has a great [tutorial about creating Master-Detail interface](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CocoaBindings/Tasks/masterdetail.html)s online.
The screenshots are a bit outdated if you are using Xcode 3.2, but it's not that different.

NSViewController has a [representedObject](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSViewController_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSViewController/representedObject) property, which allows you to bind to the model object that you are currently displaying.

**Edit:**
OK. My answer isn't that great because it's only half the truth.
While it shows how to bind your controls within the detail view, it does not provide a solution on how to bind the selection of the array controller to the view controller's `representedObject`.
I would be interested in a bindings-only solution to this problem.